# Why do meshes show up as bones in the Model class?

Tags: xna, models

Right now I'm working on a 3D game and I've come across something very weird. When I created the model in Blender, I added an armature named "MyBone" to the stage and attached a cube ("MyCube") to it, so that when I move the armature, the cube moves with it. I exported this as an FBX and loaded it as a Model object.

What I expected to see was:

But what I got was this:

I'm really confused. Why is the mesh I created showing up in the bone list? And what's Root Node?

Here are the .blend and .fbx files: [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?959hkpzrv0no9iq) or [here](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=49V7F9NM).

Thanks.

Comment: ImageShack seems to have deleted your images [and replaced them with ad banners.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771) If you can, please reupload the images (or something equivalent) using the image upload button in the editor toolbar (which will upload them to Stack Exchange's imgur account).

Comment: Alas, without the missing images, it's pretty much impossible to tell what this question is asking about.

Comment: The images appear to have been replaced with spam, so I removed them and closed the question.

Comment: I have locked this and kept it as an example of what link rot can do.

Answer (score 2):

I think your model hierarchy is wrong because you must use bones instead of armatures for animated models that will be imported by XNA (I haven't ever used Blender, but some quick Googling produced [these](http://www.stromcode.com/2008/03/16/modeling-for-xna-with-blender-part-iv/) [results](http://prosglobal.tv/blog/2011/07/animating-single-bones-in-a-blender-3d-model-with-xna/))

And the Root Node is an automatically generated bone that acts as the parent of all the objects present in the scene.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Can you explain what is the difference between armatures and bones? Anyway the fbx won't necessarily be animated.

Comment: In blender, an armature is a collection of bones (sometimes also called skeleton).